The supplied phased action failed with an exception. Could not open init generic class cache for initialization script
please help
The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
Could not open init generic class cache for initialization script 'C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\redhat.java\1.32.0\config_win\org.eclipse.osgi\56\0.cp\gradle\init\init.gradle' (C:\Users\ACER.gradle\caches\7.6.3\scripts\9iodf8hgeg304w3rl07eha3th).
BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'BuildScript' Unsupported class file major version 65
Unsupported class file major version 65 .
how i can solve such problem
